# Selecting a large number of rows by index using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to select a number of rows by the value of a column called ID. I know you can do this pretty easily by:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5...)
```

However, what if there are a few million IDs I want to select and the IDs don't always have pattern (which means I can't use something like BETWEEN x AND y)? Does this select statement still work or is there better ways of doing so?

---

The actual application is this. Filters are specified by users, which is compared to some attributes of the records. From those filters, we create a subset of the data which is of interest to a particular user. There are about 30 million records each with roughly ~3000 attributes (which is stored in roughly 30 tables, but every table has ID as a primary key), so every time someone makes a query about their desired subset of records, we'd have to join many tables, apply those filters, and figure out what his subset looks like. In order to avoid joining many tables all the time, I thought maybe it's a better idea to join the tables once, figure out the id of the selected subset, and this way each time a new query is made, all we have to do is select the relevant columns of the rows that match the filtered ids.

Comment: The above query should benefit from an index on `id` regardless of the terms in the `WHERE IN (...)` clause.  How many terms do you expect to appear there?

Comment: In general OR conditions are hard to optimize and an IN list is nothing else then a gigantic OR condition. Depending on the DBMS being used, rewriting it to a JOIN against a VALUES clause, often produces a better execution plan. But an IN list with "millions of values" sounds like a really strange approach. Where do those "millions" come from? Can't you just use a sub-query instead of hardcoding all the values?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - as the post said, could go from anywhere between a hundred thousand to a few millions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Actually BigQuery I am using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I've made an update to the question so hopefully that clarifies your second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the database and the interface you are using.  For a few hundred or thousand values, no problem.  But your question specifies *millions*.  And that could start to get into limits on the length of the query -- either specified by the database, the tool you are using, or intermediate libraries.

If you have so many ids, I would strongly recommend that you load them into a table in the database with the `id` as the primary key.  Then use `join` or `exists` to identify the rows in your table that match.

Often, such a list would be generated in the database anyway.  In that case, you can use a subquery or CTE and just include that code in your final query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've made a bit of a clarification to the question so hopefully this makes it more clear. As I said, the IDs are user generated, so I can't load it into a table.

Comment: @Winston . . . Your approach is probably not a better way.  You should be storing the results (either as a list of ids or rows) in tables in the database.  You should not be passing millions of ids back and forth into the application.  Actually, this is covered in this answer.

Comment: What if different users may select different rows and the ids are all temporary? For example, the first user may have set their filters as col1 IN (1,2,3), col2 IN (4,5,6) which have resulted in IDs (1,2,3,4,5) matching while user two may have some other filters which resulted in different IDs being matched? The IDs depend on the filters, which if different every time? Thanks

Comment: @Winston . . . You are presumably storing the ids because they are going to be used multiple times (per user).  You can have a single table with something like `user_id`, `run_id`, `id` and use this for joining.  That table will get really big, but you can handle that by partitioning by time or some other attribute.